# QML Opacity Inheritance

Tags: opacity, qml

In QML, how can I prevent a child element from inheriting the opacity from its parent? 
I want to set different opacity values for the parent and it's child element.

Answer (score 16):

I think, one way would be to use semi transparent colors as described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-color.html) instead of opacity.

e.g. using quad color code like `#800000FF` for semi transparent blue.

Comment: If you can assign a single color directly (not a composite item and not an image), this solution is perfect.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. I actually just set #00000000, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: To emphasize, the transparency digits are the **first two** digits. Different alpha values can be found in this chart: https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4

Answer (score 15):

Actually, setting `layer.enabled: true` for the parent element does the thing for me.
The whole element is rendered to the buffer, and `opacity` is applied to the resulting buffer (to the whole layer at once).

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#layer.enabled-prop

Example code:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 200
    opacity: 0.5
    layer.enabled: true
    Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            color: 'red'
    }
    Rectangle {
            width: parent.width / 2
            height: parent.height
            color: 'blue'
    }
}
```

That is a solution, but make sure that you know what you are doing when enabling layering.

Another possible solution would be using a shadereffect.

Thanks to peppe on #qt@freenode.

Comment: Nope! 'layer.enabled'  wont do that

Comment: [Layer Opacity vs Item Opacity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#layer-opacity-vs-item-opacity).   So `layers.enabled`  controls item by item alpha blending

Answer (score 10):

You can't. Items opacity value is relative to their parents one, so if you code something like

```
Rectangle {
  color: "red"
  opacity: 0.5
  width: 200; height: 100

  Rectangle {
    color: "blue"
    opacity: 1
    width: 100; height: 100
  }
}
```

You will see that the two rectangles have the same opacity.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior even now. Frankly, I can't see a reason for such a choice, I suspect it's a bug.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. It's the same form many common properties (e.g.: x, y, z). It allows you not to arrange every Item using absolute references.

Comment: I tried to open a bug against QtQml, it has been closed in minutes, so it seems that Qt folks are of your same opinion. But I'm still skeptik about this matter. If I write a line of code, I don't want it to be ignored in first place, secondly if it has to be ignored, I'd like to be warned that my code has not effect. But, again, I can't see a reason why, if a block of elements have opacity 0.5, I can't make just one of it having opacity 1. And if they are logically grouped as children of the main container, why should I make just one of it a sibling?

Comment: If you set the opacity of a group of Items to 0.5, it means to me (and to Qt guys) that you want to set that value to all the Items in the group. Otherwise you should set this value just to the Items you want to.

Comment: What I mean is to have the possibility to _add an exception_ to the opacity policy of the group. If you have tens of elements inside a logical group, and you want just only one of it to behave differently from the others, why should you pick it up and place it apart from the others? I mean, the logical hierarchy of the elements exists regardless of the opacity of its members.

Comment: You can add a custom `defaultOpacity` property to the root, and point the opacity of each child to that or set a specific value in the "exceptional" ones. Of course I'm not sayng this is THE right way of treating the opacity inheritance; it just makes sense to me.

Comment: yeah... that's how opacity typically works in a scene graph: a node's opacity is the node's local opacity multiplied by it's ancestors, opacity. For this reason, if the parent has a local opacity of 0.5 and the child has a local opacity of 1.0, the resulting opacity for the child will be parent's opacity (0.5) x child local opacity (1.0) = 0.5. However, I would expect that putting the opacity value to 2.0 would work, because 0.5 * 2.0 = 1.0. I tried it and it didn't work unfortunately. It looks like Qt is clamping the opacity values between 0 .. 1 too soon... :(

Answer (score 8):

I've bumped into this issue just now. Using Qt 5.1.0

In my case, I had a `Rectangle` Element with `opacity: 0.6` and a child `Image` element. The `Image` was inheriting the transparency - not desired.

To solve it, I enclosed the main `Rectangle` in an `Item` element. Passed the size/position definitions from the `Rectangle` to the outer `Item`. Moved the `Image` outside the `Rectangle`.

In the end, I had `Item` as the main parent and `Rectangle` and `Image` side by side, inside `Item`.

Only `Rectangle` maintained the opacity 0.6, so the Rectangle has transparency and `Image` is fully opaque.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible! You need to test in the `Component.onCompleted` scope the opacity of the parent. If its 0 you need to change the parent of your object to the parent of it's current parent.

Example:

```
Item{
    id:root

    Item{
        id:currentParent
        opacity: 0
        Item{
            id:item
            Component.onCompleted:{
                if(parent.opacity === 0)
                    item.parent = currentParent.parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot prevent the child element from inheriting the opacity from its parent.

My personal work around is to change this:

```
Rectangle {
    color: "red"
    opacity: 0.5
    width: 200; height: 100

    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        opacity: 1
        width: 100; height: 100
    }
}
```

Into this:

```
Item {
    width: 200; height: 100

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
        opacity: 0.5
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        opacity: 1
        width: 100; height: 100
    }

}
```

or this (only possible if the parent is a solid color):

```
Rectangle {
    color: "#7FFF0000" // 50% transparent red
    opacity: 0.5
    width: 200; height: 100

    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        opacity: 1
        width: 100; height: 100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its possible. you have to make two element sibling and changes its opacity as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible to do that but you can change their color with

`Qt.lighter(color,opacity)`

for example

```
Rectangle {
  color: Qt.lighter("red",.5)
  width: 200; height: 100

  Rectangle {
    color: Qt.lighter("blue",1)
    width: 100; height: 100
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem with Qt 4.8.6.

In my particular case, I wanted the top level item to be 20% transparent with black color, but have its child elements be unaffected by any opacity/transparency setting from the parent.

Opacity did not work, due to the inheritance mechanism of QML.

But I was able to use the rgba function from the Qml Qt object. This allowed me to get exactly what I wanted, the parent is now 20% transparent, but the child elements are unaffected.

```
Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    color: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) // Works perfectly, pure black with 20% transparency, equal to 0.2 opacity

    // Unaffacted child elements here...
}
```

Note: I also tried to use the RGBA color codes directly, as mentioned by a previous poster, but it did not work.

Example:

```
color: "#000000FA" // Supposed to be semi transparent, but always transparent, regardless of the alpha value
```

Setting the alpha value for any other RGBA values worked, just not with pure black.

Comment: the color property in QML is ARGB, not RGBA. Change your color to `#FA000000` and it will work.

Comment: You are correct. Perhaps, because I was working with Qt.rgba(..) previously, I got it stuck in my mind at the time that the color type was using the same format.