# How does opacity work in QML?

Tags: qml, opacity

I don't understand the behavior of opacity in the following code!

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 640; height: 480

    Rectangle {
        id: wrapper
        width: 600; height:440
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "black"
        opacity: 0.5

        Rectangle {
            id: belowcover
            width: cover.width / 2
            height: cover.height / 2
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "green"
            z: 1
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: cover
            width: root.width / 2
            height: root.height / 2
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "red"
            z: 1
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: seen
            width: 100; height: 100
            radius: width
            color: "blue"
            z: -1
        }
    }
}
```

The `wrapper` has opacity of 0.5 so that I could see through it in order to see the circle `seen`. But both `cover` and `belowcover` have opacity of 1, and as `belowcover` is smaller than `cover`, it should not be seen (or rather I expect it not to be seen, or am I missing something?). But both `cover` and `belowcover` are seen. I want only the circle to be seen through `wrapper`, and `belowcover` is to remain hidden below `cover`. How can I do this? I have observed that setting the `z` of `cover` higher than that of `belowcover` does not make the latter hidden.

**Edit**:
I have observed that when opacity of parent is set to less than 1, the children objects become less opaque, even though their `opacity` remains at 1, as seen when printed to console. I don't understand why.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204226/qml-opacity-inheritance/26998032#26998032) question about opacity and the related answer. Generally speaking opacity is *always* inherited from the parent, i.e. you have to set a common `item` parent with `opacity: 1` to tune the opacity of the children. Also [`layer`s](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#item-layers) can help in certain cases but at an higher cumputational cost.

Comment: Thanks. So `opacity` goes along the same line as other properties like `x`, `y`, etc. Thus, even though child *has* `opacity` of 1(analogous to `x` value of 0, when absolute `x` may not be 0), it is relative to that of the parent. Nice consistency, though confused me initially! I think you should move your comment to answers for future readers.

Comment: The choice about opacity is both a consistency choice (a not visible control should have all its children not visible) and a performance choice (layered rendering is costly).

Well, I didn't answer because I'm quite sure this question is a duplicate...just can't find the duplicate!  :D

Comment: ok, here is the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204226/qml-opacity-inheritance I found it for you ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why a child having opacity of 1 yet appearing to have transparency when its parent has opacity less than 1 is: opacity goes along the same line as other properties like `x`, `y`, etc. Thus, even though child has opacity of 1, it is relative to that of the parent. So if parent has opacity 0.5, and child has opacity of 1, then *absolute* opacity value of child is actually 0.5. Another child with opacity of 0.5 actually has opacity of 0.5x0.5=0.25. This is analogous to `x` value of child being 0, when absolute `x` may not be 0. This design preserves consistency throughout the API.

There are [several work-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204226/qml-opacity-inheritance). The one I prefer most is to use [semi-transparent colors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-color.html) for the parent. Try setting the `color` of `wrapper` to `color: "#88000000"`. You can no longer see the green rectangle `belowcover`. To see that, you have to set the opacity of `cover` to some value less than 1, which means `cover` *is* opaque. That is how I actually solved my problem.

However, if the parent is an image, then this can't be applied. Then you have to resort to some other techniques. For example:

1. Using [layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20633727/3375713). Set `layer.enabled: true` for parent.
2. By [changing the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349454/3375713) when immediate parent has opacity less than 1.
3. Many other techniques are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204226/qml-opacity-inheritance).